# Ruby Cucumber - call a module's method in step definition

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In a step definition, when I tried to call a method defined in a module in another file, I got 'NoMethodError'.

**custom_mod.rb**:

```
module MyMod
    def my_method()
        puts "Called my_method"
    end
end
```

**sd_component.rb:**

```
require 'custom_mod'
When (/^I did something/) do
    MyMod.my_method()
end
```

And when I run it I get this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `my_method' for MyMod:Module.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a very simple fix, you just use `def self.my_method()`

This is very fundamental Ruby OOP stuff. With either modules or classes, you need to use "class methods" (that's what the `self.` does) to call methods in this way.

Compare this to instance methods:

```
module Foo2
  def bar2
    'bar2'
  end
end

class Foo
  include Foo2
  def bar
    'bar'
  end
end

Foo.new.bar # => 'bar'
Foo.new.bar2 # => 'bar2'
```

Note that instance methods work differently on modules than classes. Module instance methods can be mixed in (load them as instance methods with `include` or as class methods with `extend`). Module class methods cannot be used as mixins in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is to include your module like this:

```
require 'custom_mod'
include MyMod
When (/^I did something/) do
    my_method()
end
```